# Unable to see or modify value of PYTHONHASHSEED through a module

Tags: python, environment-variables, python-3.4

Trying to see the value of [`PYTHONHASHSEED`](https://docs.python.org/3.4/using/cmdline.html?highlight=pythonhashseed#envvar-PYTHONHASHSEED) by using:

```
# (this is inside module_1.py)
os.environ['PYTHONHASHSEED']
```

raises a KeyError:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/black/Dev/Projects/module_1.py", line 2, in <module>
    os.environ['PYTHONHASHSEED']
  File "/usr/lib/python3.4/os.py", line 631, in __getitem__
    raise KeyError(key) from None
KeyError: 'PYTHONHASHSEED'
```

Printing the contents of `os.environ` by

```
for i in sorted(os.environ):
    print(i)

# prints:
# CLUTTER_IM_MODULE
# COMPIZ_BIN_PATH
# ...
# etc.
```

reveals that `PYTHONHASHSEED` is not inside, but I am pretty sure it should  have a value since [on Python 3.3 and greater, hash randomization is turned on by default](https://docs.python.org/3.4/using/cmdline.html?highlight=pythonhashseed#cmdoption-R).

**Question:**
Why can't I access its value this way and how can I access it through `module_1.py`?

Comment: What outputs do you get from `printenv PYTHONHASHSEED` and `echo "$PYTHONHASHSEED"` in your Bash shell?

Comment: @PM2Ring I've never used my Bash shell before. I am assuming i simply paste them in the Terminal of PyCharm. If so, they do nothing at all (`echo` simply creates an empty line).

Comment: @PM2Ring Used "ctr+alt+T" to start the Ubuntu terminal, and i still get the same thing for the two commands. No results and an empty line respectively.

Comment: In that case, PYTHONHASHSEED definitely isn't defined in your environment. So you should explain in your question why you think it should be defined, eg what you've done to try & define it. It's probably easy to fix, but it's hard to offer the best suggestion when we don't know what you did wrong.

Comment: @PM2Ring I am assuming it is set, since in [python 3.3 or greater, it's turned on by default](https://docs.python.org/3.4/using/cmdline.html?highlight=pythonhashseed#cmdoption-R). I will edit accordingly.

Comment: If Python sees that PYTHONHASHSEED has been defined it will use PYTHONHASHSEED's value to override the default hashing behaviour. Python **won't** create PYTHONHASHSEED; you need to do that yourself.

Comment: I see from your Chat posts that you want to run a Python script with various values of PYTHONHASHSEED. I'll post some code that shows a simple way to do that.

Comment: @PM2Ring My goal is to verify that my processes have a different hash seed (since they get a random-one automatically) but i guess an answer that sets it to specific values would accomplish that anyway.

Comment: Well, you can see if they're using different seeds by simply printing the hash of the same string on different runs & seeing that they differ. :) But I'll post my answer anyway; you (or some future reader) may find it helpful.

Comment: Related: [extract hash seed in unit testing](https://stackoverflow.com/q/41088635)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You *can* set PYTHONHASHSEED in a Python script, but it has no effect on the behavior of the `hash()` function - it needs to be set in the environment of the interpreter before the interpreter starts up.

---

### How to set its value using pure Python

The trick is to pass the environment variable to the Python interpreter in a subprocess.

```
import random
from subprocess import call

random.seed(37)
cmd = ['python', '-c', 'print(hash("abc"))']

for i in range(5):
    hashseed = bytes(random.randint(0, 4294967295))
    print('\nhashseed', hashseed)
    call(cmd, env={'PYTHONHASHSEED': hashseed})
```

**output**

```
hashseed 2929187283
-972692480

hashseed 393430205
2066796829

hashseed 2653501013
1620854360

hashseed 3616018455
-599248233

hashseed 3584366196
-2103216293
```

You can change the `cmd` list so that it runs the `hashtest.py` script above:

```
cmd = ['python', 'hashtest.py']
```

or if `hashtest.py` is executable,

```
cmd = './hashtest.py'
```

By passing a `dict` as the `env` argument we replace the default environment that would be passed to the command. If you need access to those other environment variables, then instead you should modify `os.environ` in the calling script, with eg, `os.environ['PYTHONHASHSEED'] = hashseed`.

### How to set its value using Bash

First, we have a short Bash script `pyhashtest.bsh` that uses the RANDOM environment variable as the seed for PYTHONHASHSEED. This variable must be exported so that the Python interpreter can see it. Then we run our Python script `hashtest.py`. We do this in a loop 5 times so we can see that using different seeds has an effect on the hash value.

The Python script `hashtest.py` reads PYTHONHASHSEED from the environment and prints it to show that it has the value we expect it to have. We then calculate & print the hash of a short string.

**pyhashtest.bsh**

```bash
#!/usr/bin/env bash

for((i=0; i<5; i++)); do
    n=$RANDOM
    echo "$i: Seed is $n"
    export PYTHONHASHSEED="$n"
    python hashtest.py
    echo
done
```

**hashtest.py**

```python
#!/usr/bin/env python
import os

s = 'abc'
print('Hashseed is', os.environ['PYTHONHASHSEED'])
print('hash of s is', hash(s))
```

**typical output**

```
0: Seed is 9352
Hashseed is 9352
hash of s is 401719638

1: Seed is 24945
Hashseed is 24945
hash of s is -1250185385

2: Seed is 17661
Hashseed is 17661
hash of s is -571990551

3: Seed is 24313
Hashseed is 24313
hash of s is 99658978

4: Seed is 21142
Hashseed is 21142
hash of s is -662114263
```

To run these programs, save them both into the same directory, eg the usual directory you run Python scripts from. Then open a Bash shell and navigate to that directory using the `cd` command.

Eg, if you've saved the scripts to `/mnt/sda2/fred/python` then you'd do

```
cd /mnt/sda2/fred/python
```

Next, make `pyhashtest.bsh` executable using this command:

```
chmod a+x pyhashtest.bsh
```

Then run it with

```
./pyhashtest.bsh
```

---

Comment: I am trying to use dill to hash functions. However it seems affected by this randomization. Is it possible to embed this solution into my hashing function? I suppose the function to be hashed will need to be picked, sent to the new interpreter, and there it would be unpickle and pickled again. Currently I am hashing the bytecode, but it seems to be less portable and much slower.

Comment: @dawid If you have your own hash function (or [`__hash__`](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/datamodel.html#object.__hash__) method) you can easily bypass the hash randomization: just don't call `hash()` directly on a `str` or `bytes`. Eg, split it into a tuple, like this: `hash(tuple(b'abc'))`.

Comment: @dawid Maybe you should ask a fresh question, explaining clearly *why* you need to hash functions so readers can understand what properties the resulting hash needs. You can link back to this question if you think it'll help readers to understand your problem. Or drop by the [SO Python chatroom](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/6/python) to discuss it.

Comment: I am hashing functions to have a (probabilistically) unique deterministic identifier across runs and machines. Unfortunately, for security purposes PYTHONHASHSEED interferes with pickle/dill. This is my question:  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70129138/how-to-make-dill-deterministic/70129236#70129236

Comment: @dawid I'd just hash the bytecode (and the function's local values), like [this](https://sagecell.sagemath.org/?z=eJxNj2ELwiAQhr_vVxw0SCsGNSII9ltkOd2kTTd1FIz-e6cJeZ_uHnzuXqU1EwytG0b1ADXNxnqYumtRdEKCJO0JluZ8o_cCsB7QQH2JrRV-tRrJAVo4wvIT-iDYv8CDUOcCT4JNF1bNWThPZKbIijFuOsFYRA4Rr7iJDF25L7c0a-fdp9yCgOvadfSOsQSerwztK6GDTmhcuZut0p44mmfDfyOpBvHuVC-cx7eFNDaGBKWByBP0KebPz-JjR-kXdbdh8A==&lang=python). That *should* be fast & portable, but I don't know if it's suitable for your use-case.

Answer (score 2):

"hash randomization is turned on by default" means (among other things) that it is turned on even if there is no `PYTHONHASHSEED` environment variable - if the hash seed is not specified in the environment, one is chosen at random. This choice is done internally within python, and the `os.environ` array is not updated.

Comment: Exactly. Is it possible to access this random seed when `PYTHONHASHSEED` is random or not defined?

Comment: I don't know, sorry - in fact I found this Stack Exchange post while looking for the answer to that exact question.

Comment: I dug through the CPython source a bit in search of this answer.  It doesn't look to be exposed; it's stashed as the `hash_seed` within the PyInterpreterState's core config on the C side.

Comment: OK, so it should be possible to write a C extension module to access it. Seems a bit excessive though...