# How to set PYTHONHASHSEED in python file

Tags: python, word2vec

I'm trying to set PYTHONHASHSEED=0 in my python file and my python version is 3.6.
I'm using **Word2Vec** model "(`Word2Vec(description, min_count=1, size= 100, workers=3, window =3, sg = 1, seed=0)`)", i am not getting the consistent result.

Is there any way I can set the PYTHONHASHSEED for my python filename.py?

Comment: By the time Python is running, it's far too late to set `PYTHONHASHSEED`. You need to do that before you run Python.

Comment: can you tell me how to set PYTHONHASHSEED=0, when i try PYTHONHASHSEED=0 python filename.py i am getting an error as "'PYTHONHASHSEED' is not recognized as an internal or external command", i tried with 'seed=0' but not getting the constant result. is there a way to do get the constant result in word2vec ?

Comment: If you're doing this to get reproducible gensim word2vec results, the `workers=3` will also need to be changed, but also, enforcing this sort of determinism for word2vec is usually a bad idea, for reasons described in the gensim FAQ: https://github.com/RARE-Technologies/gensim/wiki/Recipes-&-FAQ#q11-ive-trained-my-word2vecdoc2vecetc-model-repeatedly-using-the-exact-same-text-corpus-but-the-vectors-are-different-each-time-is-there-a-bug-or-have-i-made-a-mistake-2vec-training-non-determinism - better to ensure your data/parameters/next-steps are robust to small variances, run-to-run.

Comment: related: https://stackoverflow.com/a/32540103, https://stackoverflow.com/q/41088635

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to set the environment variable `PYTHONHASHSEED` to 0 *before* Python is even running. If you start Python from the terminal you can do something like:

```
export PYTHONHASHSEED=0
python ...
```

We can test it works by looking at the hash of a string and how it changes between runs of Python:

```
$ python -c 'print(hash("hi"))'
-6850579690611595074
$ python -c 'print(hash("hi"))'
-5185907786673828222

$ export PYTHONHASHSEED=0

$ python -c 'print(hash("hi"))'
-8951030814243160003
$ python -c 'print(hash("hi"))'
-8951030814243160003
```

Note that this is likely not the only cause of possible indeterminism in a deep learning model. For example, for PyTorch, see [Reproducibility](https://pytorch.org/docs/stable/notes/randomness.html).

Comment: Note the method of setting the environment variable may vary by OS. (The asker might be on Windows.) But in all cases, it must be established *before* the `python` interpreter starts, to affect python's `dict`-randomization.

Comment: For Windows, the equivalent would be `set PYTHONHASHSEED=0` in the terminal, prior to running Python from that terminal.

Comment: Btw, the randomisation is more than just about dicts (e.g. sets, string hashes too), and in fact has less effect on dicts as of Python 3.6+, as dicts now preserve insertion order, as opposed to having their 'order' affected by hash randomisation.